# Changing the value of the first letter of each word

Tags: jquery, css

I'm attempting to either use jQuery, CSS or PHP to increase the font size of the first letter of each word in a string.  For example, I'm going to have a title in h1 tags like so:

```
<h1>The title of this page goes here</h1>
```

I'm wanting to text transform all the text to uppercase (no problem with CSS), but then increase the font size of the first letter that appears in the string.  With CSS or jQuery, is there a way to select the first letter of each word and modify it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $('h1').text().split(' ');
    var html = '';
    $.each(words, function() {
        html += '<span style="font-size:200%">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
    });
    $('h1').html(html);
});
```

Here's an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hCvsu/1/

Comment: This only does the first character. User asked for first character of each word, which requires a fair amount more scripting.

Comment: Awesome...this worked.  Just to note for anyone in the future, the jsfiddle link didn't seem to work, but the solution provided did.  Thanks!

Comment: An advantage here is the combination of `text` and `html`, which should keep HTML entities (though, any code can easily be adapted for that, if needed).

Comment: Having a `span`nested inside a `h1`would affect SEO?

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't get `:first-letter` to work, but here's a possible solution, assuming the `<h1>` does not contain additional tags or entities:

```
$('h1').html(function(i,html){
    return html.replace(/(\S)(\S*)/g, '<span class="FirstLetter">$1</span>$2');
});
```

CSS:

```
.FirstLetter {color:green}
```

A possible benefit here is that this should work on all browsers.
The regex is fairly simple: `\S` stands for a non-whitespace character. It matches word by word and captures the first letter in each word in the first group (`$1`), and the rest of the letters in the second group (`$2`), for an easy replace.

Working example: http://jsbin.com/ufovi4

Comment: +1 I was trying to think of how to do it with a regex. I like this one.

Comment: Very neat solution. I'll try to remember it for future use.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably just straight CSS, though it creates a bit extra markup for you to write. JQuery would end up making the same amount of extra markup, though, with extra overhead, and would fail without JS support.
    h1.dropcaps div{
        float:left;
    }
    h1.dropcaps div:first-letter {
        font-size : 300%;
        font-weight : bold;
    }

```
<h1 class="dropcaps"><div>Your</div> <div>text</div> <div>here</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
It turns out :first-letter does not work inside an inline element in some browsers.

The trick to fix this is to put them in divs, and float the divs. I have revised my markup.
http://jsfiddle.net/MBZaw/

Answer (score 1):

Ajma solution works if you have only one h1 in your page.

This works for all h1 :

```
  $('h1').each(function() {
     var jqt = $(this);
     var txt = jqt.text();
     jqt.html('<span style="font-size:200%">'+txt.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+ txt.substring(1));
  });
```

Possible improvements : instead of a span with a style, create a span with a class and do font-size:200% in CSS.

Possible problems : if your h1 contains other tags (which it should not!) those tags are lost, only text is retained.

Hope it helps, 
Simone

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCvsu/2/)

```
var h1 = $('h1'),
    words = h1.html().split(' '),
    withCaps = '';
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    withCaps += '<span>' + words[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + '</span>' + words[i].substring(1) + ' ';

h1.html(withCaps);
```

Comment: very nice...thnx for that option...i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Just set in your CSS to `h1 span {font-size: 125%}`, or whatever.

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var words = $this.text().split(' ');
    var newHtml = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
         newHtml += '<span>' + words[i].substring(0, 1) + '</span>' + words[i].substring(1) + ' ';
    }
    $this.html(newHtml);
});
```