# Change color of first character of a word in php

Tags: php, colors, character

I want to change color of First character of each word in php like

```
Example Stack
```

here i want to change color of 'E' of example and 'S' of Stack to BLUE.

i tried this

```
foreach($chars as $char)
$regexp .= $char . '[a-z0-9]+ ';
$regexp = '^' . rtrim($regexp, ' ') . '$'; 
$req = "SELECT loc_name "
."FROM table "
." WHERE loc_name REGEXP '$regexp'"; 
$query = mysql_query($req);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$results[] = array('label' => $row['loc_name']);
}
```

Comment: i dont see anything in your code for change text colour

Comment: Just in case you can do that client side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021868/changing-the-value-of-the-first-letter-of-each-word

Comment: yes i want to implement on $row['loc_name']....I used #(\s|^)([a-z0-9-_]+)#i not not working..

Comment: i cant not do on client side due to some limitation...i am doing for autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$text = 'Example Stack';
$text = preg_replace('/(\b[a-z])/i','<span style="color:blue;">\1</span>',$text);
echo $text;
?>
```

[phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zx8-84i)