# CSS pseudo selector

Tags: jquery, css

```
<h2>AUTHOR NAME </h2>
```

I like to target  first letter of first word(A) and first letter of last word (N) without using any span or class. How can I do this ?

Comment: This is easy, you can't target characters, only elements, so you'll have to wrap the characters either way.

Comment: your title doesn't make much sense or you are looking for an only CSS method which doesn't exists

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Anything is possible

Comment: @oGeez According to the title and tagging of Op's question!

Comment: CSS supports `:first-letter`, but it can only be used to match the first letter of the first word.

Comment: How can I do it by jQuery ?

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman you would need to use some inline-block as `span` and use some class which, we don't know why, you don't want to use

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman, doing it with jQuery would require you to add an element around the first letters so they can be styled independently, and you explicitly mentioned in your question that you do not want to do that.

Comment: I need to target dynamically because I will use this for wordpress. And the <h1> content will be generated from server. My <h1> content is not fixed. So it is not possible to use <span>. I just need to target first letter of every words.

Comment: Then wrap each word with an `<h1>` tag and use css `:first-letter`?

Comment: @Hasanuzzaman "I just need to target first letter of every words" You should have specified it in question instead of: "first letter of last word"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can selet the First letter of second word, But you can select first letter by `first-letter`

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/C5f4C/)**

**CSS**

```
h2:first-letter {
    color:red;
    font-size:35px;
}
```

You can do it via jQuery

**[See this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hCvsu/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $('h2').text().split(' ');
    var html = '';
    $.each(words, function() {
        html += '<span style="font-size:200%">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
    });
    $('h2').html(html);
});
```

Taken from other [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021868/changing-the-value-of-the-first-letter-of-each-word) and answered by [Ajma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60117/ajma)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it using CSS, however jQuery will do this in just a few lines. If you wanted each (first) letter as an element within an object, how about the `map()` method:

```
letters = $.trim($('h2').text()).split(' ').map(function(v){
    return v.substring(0,1);
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/9QVw5/)

Or if you wanted to wrap those letters in a span (to maybe style):

```
letters = $.trim($('h2').text()).split(' ').map(function(v){
    fl = v.slice(0,1);
    return '<span>'+fl+'</span>'+v.slice(1,v.length);
}).join(' ');
```

`letters` would instead contain a HTML-formatted string.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/9QVw5/1/)

Comment: letters.css({"color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"}); why it is not working ?

Comment: `letters` isn't a jQuery collection, you need to `find()` the spans within their container: [`find('span').css({...})`](http://jsfiddle.net/9QVw5/2/)

Comment: I is not still working. where is my problem ?                              <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <h1>MY NAME</h1>


 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">

 </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   letters = $.trim($('h2').text()).split(' ').map(function(v){
       fl = v.slice(0,1);
       return '<span>'+fl+'</span>'+v.slice(1,v.length);
   }).join(' ');

   $(letters).find('span').css({"color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"}); 
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Because you've changed the tag to a `h1` when the selector matches only `h2`s

Comment: I am really sorry for this. But It is also not working                 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <h2>MY NAME</h2>


 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">

 </script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

   letters = $.trim($('h2').text()).split(' ').map(function(v){
       fl = v.slice(0,1);
       return '<span>'+fl+'</span>'+v.slice(1,v.length);
   }).join(' ');

   $(letters).find('span').css({"color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"}); 
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You aren't replacing the content of `h2`! Look at this fiddle, it replaces the html inside `h2`: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zxmux/) using `html()`

Comment: My purpose to give Another style like css({"color":"yellow","font-size":"200%"}); }) in every first letter of every word within <h2> tag. How can I do this ?

Comment: That isn't what you asked, this discussion is becoming over-extended. Please ask another question if you feel you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words...it's not possible using css. You will need the help javascript to get around this limitation which in fact is quite easy using javascript

Comment: Why not just HTML and putting the words in a `span` tag?

Comment: Well he stated he didn't want to use spans or divs

Comment: And how will you do it with JavaScript without HTML elements?

Comment: Huh? What do you mean "without elements"? The text he wants to select is inside a heading tag (aka html element). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am very interested in seeing a JavaScript solution that doesn't need to inject spans (or similar) in the HTML

Comment: To do what? To select an html element? I'm not sure getting you guys...why do you need a span to select a heading tag (h2, h3, etc)? What exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

W3C [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) has only `first-letter` pseudo class. So you need wrap your letters in a single tag, for example `span`.